# How to properly declare method in custom Flutter class

Tags: flutter, dart, methods

I have created a custom class from the Floating Action Bubble package, to make it reusable. Now, if I declare the method `customBubble` as shown below, (which I am not sure it is the right way), everything works fine, apart the fact that I cannot access `_animationController!.reverse()` before the **initState**.

Else, if I declare the method `customBubble` inside `class _FabAddCategoryState`, the problem is that I am not able to access it from other class/screens.
Can you help me to write it in the right way?

**the code:**

```
class FabAddCategory extends StatefulWidget {
final List<Bubble>? items ;
const FabAddCategory({Key? key, this.items}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  State<FabAddCategory> createState() => _FabAddCategoryState();

  Bubble customBubble({required IconData icon, TextStyle? titleStyle, Color? iconColor,
    required String title, MaterialColor? bubbleColor, required Null Function() onPress, }) {
    return Bubble(icon: icon, iconColor: Colors.white, title: title,
        titleStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
        bubbleColor:  Colors.amber,
        onPress: (){
          //_animationController!.reverse();
          onPress.call();
        });
  }
}

class _FabAddCategoryState extends State<FabAddCategory> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  Animation<double>? _animation;
  AnimationController? _animationController;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 260),
    );
    final curvedAnimation = CurvedAnimation(curve: Curves.easeInOut, parent: _animationController!);
    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(curvedAnimation);
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionBubble(
      items: widget.items!,
      animation: _animation!,
      onPress: () =>
      _animationController!.isCompleted ?
      _animationController!.reverse()
          : _animationController!.forward(),
      iconColor: Colors.white, backGroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      iconData: Icons.menu,
    );
  }
  
}
```